# IBM DS300 SAN, Need to expand partitions on LUN

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, lun

I have a IBM DS300 SAN, and I have setup one LUN with 2.7 TB. I have this LUN setup with 2 partitions, one 130GB partition, and one 1.27TB partition. I have an additional 1.3TB free space. I would like to expand the 1.27TB partition, but I don't see this option under the IBM DS Storage Manger. How do I expand the partitions on the LUN using the DS Storage Manager? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it via command line.

http://run.tournament.org.il/ibm-ds4300-expand-logical-drive-lun/

But, just a heads up, don't forget the space before "GB" else you will get a syntax error.